# in C# try -catch , can't catch the exception

Tags: c#, try-catch

below code can't catch the exception.

does  `catch`  can't catch the exception which occured in the function?

```
 try
 {
   Arche.Members.Feedback.FeedbackBiz_Tx a = 
     new Arche.Members.Feedback.FeedbackBiz_Tx();

   a.AddFreeSubscriptionMember(
     itemNo, buyerID, itemName, 
     DateTime.Today,DateTime.Today);
 }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
   RegisterAlertScript(ex.Message);
 }
```

...

```
public void AddFreeSubscriptionMember(
  string itemNo, string buyerID, string itemName,
  DateTime fsStartDate, DateTime fsEndDate)
{
  FeedbackBiz_NTx bizNTx = new FeedbackBiz_NTx();

  if (bizNTx.ExistFreeSubscription(buyerID, itemNo))
  {
    throw new Exception("Exception.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possibly that the exeception isn´t thrown, cause the condition evaluates to false?

Comment: this should work... maybe the "RegisterAlertScript" raises another axception?

Comment: there is this brilliant thing called the debugger...

Answer (score 5):

Yes it will catch the exception even know it is thrown from within another function that you are calling.

Either the exception isn't being thrown, or you aren't detecting properly that the exception is caught, maybe put a breakpoint at both places.

Answer (score 2):

If the `ExistFreeSubscription` function causes a stack overflow, it won't be caught.

Also, it's possible for the function to throw an exception object that doesn't inherit from `System.Exception` (this is possible in other languages, it's not CLS compliant). `catch (Exception ex)` won't catch such kind of exceptions (a `catch { }` block can catch exception objects even if they are not inherited from `System.Exception`).

Answer (score 0):

That should work, I would look closer at your .ExistFreeSubscription() method, to see why it's not returning true.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (bizNTx.ExistFreeSubscription(buyerID, itemNo))
{
    throw new Exception("Exception.");
}
```

If `bizNTx.ExistFreeSubscription` returns `false`, then it looks like your Exception won't be thrown